# PHP - possible hurdles when executing long script

Tags: php, loops, memory, foreach, ini

I have a quite long loop running in a function , but does not finish all the eventual iterations and stops without giving any errors  :

```
function my_function(){

    foreach (range(100,999) as $art_id){ 
        
    
    $current++;//see bottom flush functions...
    outputProgress($current, $art_id );//see bottom flush functions...

// do a lot of stuff on remote URL...
    // including download images , 
    // scraping HTMl etc ..
    
    }
}
```

I am using some output progress with flush to track the progress

```
function outputProgress($current, $total) {
    // echo "<span style='background:red;font-size:1.5em;color:#fff;'>" . round($current / $total * 100) . "% </span>";
    echo "<span style='background:red;font-size:1.5em;color:#fff;'>" . $current .'/'. $total  . "% </span>";
    myFlush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

and

```
function myFlush() {
    echo(str_repeat(' ', 256));
    if (@ob_get_contents()) {
        @ob_end_flush();
    }
    flush();
}
```

(never mind the percentage calculation , it is now disabled and just shows the ID of iteration)

I have noticed that most of the time I am executing the loop,
It will just STOP after 20-25 iterations . sometimes as little as 10.

My first suspects were the `time limit` , and `max_execution time`, so I added  :

```
set_time_limit(99999);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 99999);

function my_function(){

    foreach (range(410,499) as $art_id){ // done 500-600

    set_time_limit(99999);
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 99999);
    
    // do a lot of stuff on remote URL...
    // including download images , 
    // scraping HTMl etc ..
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have added those both `INSIDE` and `OUTSIDE` the function itself, just in case .

But it does not help much , and the loop still stops .
My next suspect was the `Memory limit`, so I added :

```
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');
```

and since I am working on wp, I also tried

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

but to no avail. The scipt still stops after little iterations .

- **What are the other  possible causes for this behavior , and the
  possible remedies ?**

Mind you - the script does not give any errors, it just stops at a certain loop.

**EDIT I**

I have pasted the script [HERE](http://pastebin.com/nSQhVx1h)
. it is actually a slightly modified scrap_slashdot() function from the [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) lib included examples.

It is modified to insert wordpress posts while also downloading images and attaching them.

**EDIT II**
Using @Allendar comment `echo ini_get('memory_limit');` seems like it works and it is set to 128M..

Comment: set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and see if there is an error. If your script is failing due to one of the problems you suspect, the interpreter will tell you. also, try not to suppress errors using `@`. You may also not be able to use `ini_set` in a shared environment.

Comment: I would take out range() and put it in a variable. `foreach (range(100,999) as $art_id)` -> `$range = range(100, 999); foreach($range as $ard_id)` or just do a for loop like this `for($i=100;$i<1000;$i++){`

Comment: @Prisoner - I am already working in debug mode on wordpress with error reporting on .. but there are no errors ...

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV - this is a good advice , and actually ,I have already tried it , as well as MANUAL input of array(100,101,102..) which was a bit better ,  but still the fails all the same .

Comment: Try `if(!ini_set("max_execution_time", 99999)){ echo "failed";exit;}` If you get "failed" then it means that ini_set() doesn't work for some reason ...

Answer (score 1):

I've speeded up `usleep(50000);` to test. This code take a fragment of a second to complete on PHP `5.4` and causes no memory leakage:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M'); // Force back to default X/W/L/M/AMP

function my_function(){
    $current = 0;

    foreach (range(100,999) as $art_id){ 
        $current++;
        outputProgress($current, $art_id );
    }
}

function outputProgress($current, $total) {
    echo "<span style='background:red;font-size:1.5em;color:#fff;'>" . $current .'/'. $total  . "% </span>";
    myFlush();
    usleep(50000);
}

function myFlush() {
    echo(str_repeat(' ', 256));
    if (@ob_get_contents()) {
        @ob_end_flush();
    }
    flush();
}

my_function();

echo memory_get_usage();
```

I've added `$current = 0;` to cancel out a warning given by Xdebug.

The memory usage outputs only 282304 bytes (about 275,69 kiloBytes).

It might be the case that the 1-second wait each cycle might cause the script to abort on execution time.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

.. will fix this, but is not recommended ;)

If you still find the script to stop suddenly, it really must be in the part where you have your comments, that you write there is code. That code might be heavy enough on the payload of the PHP deamon to abort. Besides that there are also hosts (if the script is online) that prevent you from setting ini-values and maybe even kill the PHP process if it "zombies" around to long.

Comment: `sleep` takes in an `int`, you want `usleep`.

Comment: @Allendar - yes, the script is online at some standard host . Is it possible to check if my ini functions ahve a real effect (they must have , because when I remove set `max_execution_time()` i do get that error quite quickly

Comment: Yes; use `phpinfo()` after you set it (http://www.php.net/phpinfo). Or better, use `ini_get()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) and see if it is really set (`echo ini_get('memory_limit');`)

Comment: @Allendar - the ´usleep(5000)´ part was something I had already tried before (even if not wrote in question, I even tried without sleep at all. But no apparent change..

Comment: Then it's 100% sure in the part where your comment says you have more code `// do a lot of stuff on remote URL..`. If you can show us that part we might be able to figure out what hogs your PHP process. Also what PHP version is your host using?

Comment: @Allendar - I also suspect that it is not loop as per se , because the failure does not accrue always at the same spot (sometimes 20 sometimes 27 iterations .. ) I can always post the loop itself also..

Comment: Yes, and that's logical, because the HTTP request you (probably) make in the hidden code will likely give different results and thus take different amounts of time each time you run the script. If you do 100 cURL calls, you will 99% sure timeout your script ;)

Comment: I have pasted the script HERE : http://pastebin.com/nSQhVx1h . it is actually a slightly modified scrap_slashdot() function from the [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) lib included examples.

Comment: I did a quick read through the code and you just do too many url-calls. What might be working for you is to collect data separately in back-end scripts and then store it in a database. You simply can't call that many URL's in one PHP script that runs on a webserver; at least not while ruining the user experience. It's not good for either memory nor the cpu. Besides your own caching in the database you can let the user interact to "only" update the data from a certain item (url) it requests. This way you'll reduce the load  in the front-end script greatly.

Comment: @Allendar , I am calling the URL only twice, and anyhow there is no "user" :-) the only output is set for me to debug . This is a one-time script to help a client take all his old DB and migrate it to Wordpress WITHOUT having the DB access.

Comment: Ok SORRY I MISUNDERSTOOD. I think you SHOULD ask your HOST if you can HAVE memory-limit/execution-time removed for that script for a PERIOD of time. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is not "long" script, i have been working with arrays - actually 16 array with all having more than 650 indexes (= 14 X 650 = 9100 indexes, nvm if i am wrong in calculation). And it loads in fraction of seconds so it seems having no problem. I am sure you are doing something seriously wrong. It works fine (if i know correctly) [[(tested here online, on php 5)]](http://writecodeonline.com/php)], even without `ini_set();` (disabled by website) and the memoery usage was 63072 (in bytes ~ 63kbs ~ 0.063mb > 128mb)

**And** wanted to tell you that from where do you set `$current`? Your `my_function()` has not parameters and i would also recommend you to turn on error reporting by 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

There should be problem with online compiler you are using, try one which i used or download apache server, you can also try some free hosts.

Comment: You see `// do a lot of stuff on remote URL...
    // including download images , 
    // scraping HTMl etc ..` ? She just didn't include the code so that's why it runs in a fraction of a second when you tested it ...

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment. The OP already states it has more code in the `my_function()`.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV i wasn't telling that her code loads in fraction of seconds, i was telling that code i was working with 9100 indexes loads in fraction of second. THAT MEANS, php has no problem with more than hundreds or 2 hundreds indexes. <br> @ allender thanks, i edit my code to add answer(i forgot it.)

Comment: @Deep Every PHP user already knows this is no issue. It is good to note the finding, but it's not a constructive answer for the OP' problem.

Comment: Of course it has no problem IF the loop contains *nothing*, but if you're scrapping from other sites you have to consider the fact that to *connect* to the sites, downloading the files and perhaps even editing/processing some data that it *will* affect the time to finish the job and the memory used ...

Comment: agreed with your last line, my suggestion to @obmerk is to try another compiler or research for that compiler's capabilities. There are 2 major possibilities. 1: Your code has some serious problem 2: Compiler is not enough capable.

Comment: If you check the code the OP has posted in the comment of the other answer, your answer (and point) is made obsolete.

Comment: sorry for double commenting, @obmerk, you said that it stops after 20-25 iterations, does it stop every time by variable nos. of iterations? If it is so there is (almost) surely problem with compiler you are using.

Comment: 20-25 times is logical. If every URL-call takes about 1 to 1.2 seconds to complete it will easily trigger the 30 seconds execution limit of the scripts (assuming the `ini_set()` does not work on his host).

Comment: @Deep - what do you mean by the compiler ? I am using it on a LIVE server where I have wordpress up and running (in fact - 7 of them) . otherwise the script could not even run ..

Comment: have you tried @HamZaDzCyberDeV's suggestion, to check if `ini_set` works by `if(!ini_set("max_execution_time", 99999)){ echo "failed";exit;}`